# C++ chrono: How do I convert an integer into a time point

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

I managed to convert a time point into an integer and write it into a file using code that looks like the following code:

```
std::ofstream outputf("data");
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> dateTime;

dateTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

auto dateTimeSeconds = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(toSerialize->dateTime);
unsigned long long int serializeDateTime = toSerialize->dateTime.time_since_epoch().count();
outputf << serializeDateTime << "\n";
```

Now I'm trying to read that integer from the file, convert it into a time_point, and print it. Right now, my code looks something like this:

```
std::ifstream inputf("data");

unsigned long long int epochDateTime;
inputf >> epochDateTime;
std::chrono::seconds durationDateTime(epochDateTime);
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> dateTime2(durationDateTime);

std::time_t tt = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(dateTime2);
char timeString[30];
ctime_s(timeString, sizeof(timeString), &tt);
std::cout << timeString;
```

However, it doesn't print anything. Does anyone know where I went wrong?

Comment: Did you try debugging the code?

Comment: Make sure `inputf >> epochDateTime;` was successful. Currently you do no checking and can't conclusively prove the file is open, data was read or some other trivial annoyance didn't happen.

Comment: `"data"` is a relative path. You almost never want a relative path because it can be tricky to know ahead of time where the working directory will be.

Comment: You never use `dateTimeSeconds` so what's it for? The whole `time_point_cast` seems unnecessary. `std::time_t time_since_epoch = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(dateTime);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some strange conversions and assign to a variable that you don't use. If you want to store `system_clock::time_point`s as `std::time_t`s and restore the `time_point`s from those, don't involve other types and use the functions made for this: `to_time_t` and `from_time_t`. Also, check that opening the file and that extraction from the file works.

Example:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    {   // save a time_point as a time_t
        std::ofstream outputf("data");
        if(outputf) {
            std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> dateTime;
            dateTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
            outputf << std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(dateTime) << '\n';
        }
    }

    {   // restore the time_point from a time_t
        std::ifstream inputf("data");
        if(inputf) {
            std::time_t epochDateTime;
            if(inputf >> epochDateTime) {
                // use epochDateTime with ctime-like functions if you want:
                std::cout << std::ctime(&epochDateTime) << '\n';

                // get the time_point back (usually rounded to whole seconds):
                auto dateTime = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(epochDateTime);

                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works! Thank you. I didn't realize that time_t could be printed/outputted/inputted like a primitive data type.

Comment: @RyanHuynh You're welcome.  A `time_t` is often just an alias för a 64 bit integer.

Answer (score 0):

Putting aside the possibility of the wrong date value, the problem here is with `sizeof(timeString)`. It appears that you think it is `30`, but it in fact is the size of the `char*`, likely 8 (or maybe 4).

According to [ctime_s](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/ctime):

> the following errors are detected at runtime and call the currently installed constraint handler function:
>
> ```
>     buf or timer is a null pointer
>     bufsz is less than 26 or greater than RSIZE_MAX
> ```